# what's wrong with the following function closure?

Tags: javascript

in class Vector2 itself, if I use the following

```
Vector2.prototype.aaaScalar: ( function () {

        var min = new Vector2();

        return function ( minVal) {

            min.set( minVal);

            return this.aaa( min );

        };

    } )(),
```

It reports min has no set method, but There is set method in Vector2

If changing to the following , everything is OK

```
Vector2.prototype.aaaScalar: ( function () {

        var min;

        return function ( minVal) {

            if ( min === undefined ) {

                min = new Vector2();

            }

            min.set( minVal );

            return this.aaa( min );

        };

    } )(),
```

Edit：I checked in the first case, the calling of   var min = new Vector2(); does no returns me a fully created object.

Comment: Both of these snippets look good to me. I'm not familiar with the threes API, but I tried a simple alternative with an array instead of a Vector2 and it works fine.

Comment: Any chance you can set up a [codepen](http://codepen.io) project or something like that to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: Pretty sure I figured out what must be happening. I've added an answer below.

Comment: Please show us that `Vector` class your using (or point us to the library you've got it from). Also, when do you create this `aaaScalar` method, and how do you call it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here isn't your closure. Both of your examples are correct as far as the closures go... aaaScalar is getting assigned to the inner function you're returning with the min variable in it's closure.

The difference between the two snippets is timing. In the first example, `var min = new Vector2()` is executed at the time the aaaScalar property is set... when the IIFE runs. In the second example, `min = new Vector2()` isn't run until you actually invoke the function assigned to aaaScalar.

I think you'll find that the library you're getting Vector2 from isn't ready at the time aaaScalar is assigned, but it *is* ready by the time you actually invoke aaaScalar().

Comment: your answer shocks me. why is it caused by timing. Can I trust fucntion closure anymore?

Comment: can I fix it if I insists to use form1?

Comment: In the second example, min = new Vector2() isn't run until you actually invoke the function assigned to aaaScalar. I want to know why?

Comment: In the first example, your outer function does three things: 1) Creates the variable `min`, 2) executes `new Vector2()`, then 3) returns the inner function. In the second example, the outer function only does two things: 1) Creates the variable `min`, then 2) returns the inner function.

Comment: Keep in mind that when you return a function as you're doing here, the function is *not* immediately executed.

Comment: I've explained the problem in plain English as best I can. If you're not understanding the execution order still, I think your best bet is to put breakpoints on the lines where `new Vector2()` is called and see for yourself how they are called at different points in the execution flow.

Comment: I put the breakpoint, in the first snippet, var min = new Vector2() does not return me a fully created object, it missed all the prototype method, this is the error. But why causes it? From your answer, I cannot see clearly.

Comment: BTW, Vector2 is a class in the same file, it should be ready in any case, right?

Comment: It's because your outer function, the IIFE, is executed while you're still in the process of creating/assigning your prototype functions. All the code in the outer function is run at the time the `Vector2.prototype.aaaScalar` property is assigned.

Comment: The short answer from all this is that you should use the second snippet. :-) It has the correct flow for what you're doing here.

Comment: I think I finally got it. :-)